# GitHub copilot chat feature is not showing in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, github, github-copilot

I subscribed GitHub Copilot Features, however I can see chat features is available in VS Code Insider, but I would not find it in Visual Studio 2022. GitHub is charging for the subscription but did not provide chat features in Visual Studio 2022. Any idea how to get the chat features.

Comment: did you follow the instructions in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot-chat ?

Comment: Are you using VS Code with a remote connection? This seems to be a known error if so https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50328

Answer (score 0):

To access Copilot chat, you must first join the [waitlist](https://github.com/github-copilot/chat_waitlist_signup/join). Once the team approves your request, you will receive an email with instructions on installing Copilot Chat in visual studio 2022.

If you have business subscription you have to install this extinction
[GitHub Copilot Chat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSGitHubCopilot)

After installing the extension, navigate to Visual Studio, click on "View," and select "GitHub Copilot Chat.

Comment: I got copilot as a business subscription and the extension installed, even so the menu option for it is greyed out :/ I got copilot working though, just not the chat thingy...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Copilot **subscription** and the the Copilot chat **extension** already installed on your VS, be sure that you have **signed** with your GitHub account to get the extension enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue where
I could find "Github CoPilot" extension In Visual Studio 2022 v.17.7.7 but at the same time I could not find the "Github Copilot Chat" extension.

*The reason for this is that CoPilot Chat now requires Visual Studio 2022 v.17.8*

So Try to follow:

1. **Update Visual studio 2022** to a version newer than 17.7.7,
2. Go to Extensions > Manage Extensions
3. Install **Github Copilot** Extension
4. Login to Github account, to add Github to Visual Studio 2022
5. Install **Github Copilot Chat** Extension
6. No go to **View > Github Copilot Chat** and the chat should open